# Puppet agent doesnt run each 5 minutes

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet agent that doesn't run each 5 minutes as I specified it on the [agent] section with the runinterval = 300 and it appears to be properly configured:

```
# puppet agent --configprint all|grep -i runinterval
runinterval = 300
```

Also I tried this:

```
# puppet agent --daemonize
# puppet resource service puppet ensure=running enable=true
```

But I'm still getting the same behavior, please note that the puppet service is currently running and in [agent] section also has the parameter "daemon" set to "true":

```
# /etc/init.d/puppet status
puppet (pid  30287) is running...
```

What else can I do to ensure that the service is running? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to run provisioning manually and check errors: `puppet agent -t`. Probably you have a error at the beginning of provisioning process.

Comment: check if the last run is still in progress - if the last run is still running, a new run may not be invoked. check wwith ps aux|grep puppet

Comment: @maxd Here is the execution of your command, nothing appears to be wrong: `# puppet agent -t
Notice: Ignoring --listen on onetime run
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for host.example.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1448360240'`

@AnshuPrateek the only process that I see is the daemon of puppet: `root      2885     1  3 11:18 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/puppet agent --no-client`

Please note that the PID has changed because I restarted the service

Comment: ["If you want puppet agent to never run, you should start it with the --no-client option."](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#runinterval) - seems like this is reason of your problem.

Comment: Yes, @maxd I was looking how to override it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I found the problem, it was a line on /etc/sysconfig/puppet with the content:

```
PUPPET_EXTRA_OPTS=--no-client
```

Once I commented out the line and restarted the daemon now it runs every 5 minutes. Thanks to @maxd for the clue